# Is there a way to send information from a custom lwc to a standard experience builder component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-builder-page

I've created a custom search for orders, and now i would like to send the returned list to the standard Order List component, i.e., show the results of the custom search on the standard component. Is this possible? Should i try something different?

The point is to allow the user to create a new order with the same items as the original, which is already doable in the standard Order List, but lacks the search filters i've implemented in the custom lwc.